# Ubuntu Server 18.04 Nginx i386

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Need some help in how to install nginx in Ubuntu 18.04 i386.

I have this old server that is running ubuntu server since version 10... 
Last night decided to update from 16.04 to 18.04. Almost everything worked fine, with the exception of Nginx... After some research I saw that the bionic version doesn't support i386 platform...

So I'm kind of stuck.

I tried to force the installation of the xenial version, but without success.

What I already tried, first the normal approach:

```
apt install nginx
```

> Depends: nginx-extras (>= 1:1.17.3-8.6.0.4~xenial1)

```
apt install nginx-extras
```

> Depends: perlapi-5.22.1 (bionic doesn't exist, replaced by perl-base 5.26.1-26??)
>
> Depends: libperl5.22 (>= 5.22.1) (bionic has the 5.26 version)

After this I tried to force to manual install packages, by downloading deb package for the nginx-extras and to install with dpkg, failed because some missing dependices related to lua, so just did the same for that dependecies, deb files, dpkg to install, and finally installed the nginx-extras.
Installed with success, but in the end, it didn't run, on nginx start it tries to load a perl so file:

> "error while loading shared libraries: libperl.so.5.22: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

That was exepcted, because the version that I have in the system it's 5.26 and not the 5.22...

So what can i do to solve my problem?

Thanks

Comment: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install nginx ?

Comment: Thanks, but it's the same thing... Nginx-extras dependecies.

Comment: Just a comment for the close voter, I would rather move this to askubuntu.com instead of serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [Package: nginx](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/nginx) and following [nginx-full](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/nginx-full) or [nginx-light](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/nginx-light) shows, that architecture i386 is still supported in Bionic.

So your problem must be something else.

---

From your comment, it looks like you have http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ added as a repository in either `/etc/apt/sources.list` or some file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. From http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/dists/bionic/Release, it seems that i386 indeed is not supported

> Architectures: amd64 arm64

Looking for an entry

```
grep nginx.org /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

should reveal, which is the relevant file. Comment the appropriate line (prefix with a `#`) or remove it, then do an

```
apt-get update
```

and reinstall the package directly from the Ubuntu repository.

Comment: That's odd... [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#Ubuntu) says that i386 isn't supported.
But trying to run the nginx-full and nginx-light, it ends up in nginx-extras missing...

Comment: Forgot to write this down when calling the apt update: "Skipping acquire of configured file 'nginx/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'"

Comment: After some search, found deb packages for the nginx, so just did a trial and error to get it installed "manually", by getting the dependices for it, getting the related deb package, installed, and so on until i could installed the nginx package. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list`

Change:

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ bionic nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ bionic nginx
```

To:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ bionic nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ bionic nginx
```

Doing another apt-get update after this change it worked fine.